# amp html validation error <div style="clear:both;"> on blogger

Tags: html, blogger

i have problem about amp validation in blogger
i use old template (classic)and
when try to https://thaifoodguru.blogspot.com/2016/07/som-tum-papaya-spicy-salad.html
it have 2 error at  paragraph etc.
1. error type The attribute 'style' may not appear in tag 'div'.
2. error type The attribute 'style' may not appear in tag 'div'.
error come from post maybe

when remove it (i mean no post content) amp validation  successful
how i can solve it? please

Answer (score 0):

Make that div into class x 
Define this style for .x
This is how I made it in my AMP blogspot. You can check the source -   https://amprandom.blogspot.com